# Wrong array variable getting changed

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, for-loop, output

In the following function I clearly change the variable `rightArray` through the statement: `rightArray[i] = dataValues[i];`

However the behaviour I'm getting from the function is that the variable `leftArray` is changing in place of `rightArray`

```
//Returns the interquartile range
float StatisticalAnalyser::getInterquartileRange()
{
    float interquartileRange = 0;

    int numberOfDatums = dataFile.findNumberOfDatums();
    float numberOfDatumsFloat = dataFile.findNumberOfDatums();
    float dataValues[dataFile.findNumberOfDatums()];

    dataFile.initialiseArrayToFileData(dataValues);

    //If even number of datums
    if (numberOfDatums % 2 == 0)
    {
        //Arrays for for each side of the median
        int arraySize = numberOfDatumsFloat/2;
        float leftArray[numberOfDatums/2];
        float rightArray[numberOfDatums/2];

        //Initialise arrays for each side of the median
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDatums; i++)
        {
            if (i < numberOfDatums/2)
            {
                leftArray[i] = dataValues[i];
            }
            if (i >= numberOfDatums/2)
            {
                //leftArray SOMEHOW GETS CHANGED INSTEAD OF RIGHT ARRAY
                rightArray[i] = dataValues[i];
```

**leftArray gets changed instead of rightArray here**: `rightArray[i] = dataValues[i];`

```
            }
        }
    }

    if (numberOfDatums % 2 == 0.5)
    {
        //Not relevant, isn't triggered when problem occurs
    }

    return interquartileRange;
}
```

I am running Xcode 10.1, and want to know how to fix this error so that `rightArray` is changed by the function instead of `leftArray`.

Comment: Why the downvote? I have tried to be as clear and concise as possible and have researched similar questions on this site and google as well, but have found no satisfactory answers:/

Comment: I'm not the down-voter but questions asking for debugging are off-topic. You may read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) if in doubt. In general, it wouldn't hurt to take the [Tour] for a short intro into this site.

Comment: @Scheff Thanks for the heads up, I'll take care to go through the page carefully!

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your code but `numberOfDatums % 2 == 0.5` surely doesn't do what you expect. [`operator%`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Multiplicative_operators) is for integral values exclusively (if not overloaded) and this can never become true.

Comment: @AShinyBlueColour you have a simple error, see my answer

Comment: @Scheff I've been trying to use it to determine if `numberOfDatums` is even or odd, I'm fairly new to modulus so I might have done something incorrectly but the if statement has worked so far on a few test cases. I'll test again though and make sure, thanks.

Comment: `numberOfDatums % 2` will return 0 (even) or 1 (odd). These are the values worth to check in comparison. Comparing with 0.5 should fail always.

Comment: @Scheff I'm not even sure what I've done to get it work then lol. Thanks for the advice and I'll get to work implementing the if statement properly. EDIT: Wow I'm dumb, I don't know why I even wrote 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having

```
    float leftArray[numberOfDatums/2];
    float rightArray[numberOfDatums/2];
```

in

```
       if (i >= numberOfDatums/2)
        {
            //leftArray SOMEHOW GETS CHANGED INSTEAD OF RIGHT ARRAY
            rightArray[i] = dataValues[i];
```

you go out of *rightArray* and randomly write in *leftArray* (of course this is an undefined behavior)

must be

```
       if (i >= numberOfDatums/2)
        {
            rightArray[i - numberOfDatums/2] = dataValues[i];
```

---

Furthermore, to have

```
       if (i < numberOfDatums/2)
        {
            ...
        }
        if (i >= numberOfDatums/2)
```

with *i* unchanged is useless, the second *if* can be an *else*, but it is also better to do two *for* to not have to do `numberOfDatums/2` all the times just to decide which array to use.

Comment: Thanks you, I think I need to work on my debugging skills.